# The field for entering password freeze if no text is enter quickly after i install cinnamon on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

Iam a total newbie to Ubuntu . I installed Cinnamon through terminal . The problem is that when i boot up, if i don't enter the password before 1 or 2 minutes the password field will freeze and won't accept any text inputs.The problem was most likely caused by Cinnamon because i guess the problem started after i tried to install some Cinnamon extensions. Please answer in non-technical way as far as possible. I will never go back to Windows whatever be the outcome. Help me stay on to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem is due to the Cinnamon and you have to remove the cinnamon completely from your system.To do that ,open terminal and type this:
*sudo apt-get --purge autoremove cinnamon*

Comment: Thanks, i remove it completely. The problem is gone but the log in takes too long. After entering password and hit enter key it takes a while to log in

Comment: @UbuntuLover If it solves the problem then you should vote up the answer so that it helps other members with same problem.

Comment: @UbuntuLover, open terminal and type following: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade